# How to create requirements.txt file for cordova or ionic plugins

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

How to create python (pip) like requirements.txt file to make a list of all installed plugins to ease collaboration in ionic/cordova.

Comment: I asked for cordova/ionic node based environment not for python/pip

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ionic state` from the `ionic-cli`.

Simply do, `ionic state save` to save all platforms and plugins of the project.

And then `ionic state restore` to get back all platforms and plugins.

More details here : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli#ionic-state